# Using ActionFilterAttribute with Class Library Project (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, filter, attributes

I would like to use 'WEB API' action filter attributes over 'Class Library' class methods. Is that possible? or Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without more trouble than its worth. Action filters are a feature of Web Api, so unless you are talking about putting Web Api controllers into your own library or using filters from your library within Web Api controllers, you won't be able to take advantage of them directly.

A potential solution could be to use a [proxy pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/proxy) or [decorator pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator) to handle [cross-cutting concerns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658105.aspx) for your library. Have a look at [Aspect-Oriented Programming : Aspect-Oriented Programming with the RealProxy Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574804.aspx) for details.